# when using pip install with git urls, is possible to skip checkout and use an existing local repository?

Tags: python, git, pip

I have a project with requirments.txt file that contains entries of the form:

```
-e git+http://repo/my_project.git#egg=SomeProject
```

which checks out the repository and performs and installs the library - which is the required behaviour in most cases.

however, sometimes I want to ignore the url (and possible tag\branch pointer), and do the install from an existing clone of the repository - the equivalent of:

```
-e path/to/SomeProject
```

Is there some way to do this automatically? (without editing \ modifying the requirments.txt file)

Comment: I'm pretty sure `-e path/to/SomeProject` already works.  What happens when you try it?

Comment: it works - but my file has the git links.
I'm looking for a method that doesn't require managing two versions of the file

Comment: I'd create a wrapper script (e.g. `myinstall`). Looks like `pip` allows a `-r` option to specify an alternate requirements file. I'd have the script read the standard requirements.txt and change the contents on the fly and put into (e.g.) `/tmp/requirements_local.txt` and then have it invoke `pip -r /tmp/requirements_local.txt ...`. If you ever change the base requirements.txt, the script will adapt automatically

Answer (score 2):

I'm hopefully not out of scope, but you can do this using bash:

```
cat requirements.txt |grep -v project|xargs pip install -e path/to/project
```

This will leave out your project package from the `requirements.txt`, then replaces it with the path to the local version.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to make any changes to requirements.txt, you can setup a http server and make `repo` an alias for localhost in your `hosts` file